# Refatorar variável somente no arquivo

Tags: netbeans

Desejo refatorar uma variável somente no arquivo atual, quando refatoro ele muda em todas as páginas do projeto, como fazer?

Comment: É um projeto em java? é uma variável local ou propriedade de classe?

Comment: é um projeto web em php, na verdade é o id de uma table html